# How to use a boolean in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this very long query that works fine.  I need to add one `boolean` element to it.

EDIT:  QUERY HAS BEEN UPDATED. Reflecting answer below. New Problem: For every item it now shows a row for each rating.  For example, if 4 people rated it, it will show one row with isMatched = 1 if I was one of the raters; the other three will be isMatched = 0.  If there were two ratnigs, and I was neither, isMatched shows 0 twice.

```
   $result=mysql_query("
                SELECT i.item,
                    IF (ra.user_id = '{user}',1,0) AS isMatched, 
                r.ratetotal AS total,
                c.commtotal AS comments,
                r.rateav AS rate
                FROM items AS i
                LEFT JOIN master_cat AS c
                    ON (c.cat_id = i.cat_id)
                    LEFT JOIN ratings AS ra
                            ON (i.items_id = ra.item_id)
                LEFT JOIN
                    (SELECT item_id, 
                    COUNT(item_id) AS ratetotal, 
                    AVG(rating) AS rateav 
                    FROM ratings GROUP BY item_id) AS r 
                ON r.item_id = i.items_id
                LEFT JOIN
                    (SELECT item_id, 
                    COUNT(item_id) AS commtotal 
                    FROM comments GROUP BY item_id) AS c
                ON c.item_id = i.items_id
                WHERE c.category = '{$cat}'  AND i.spam < 30
                 {$order};");
```

I want to add one more function to this.  This is a user-based system and some users will have rated an item in a table called `ratings`.  Each rating in the table will have a `user_id` as well to match who rated the `item_id` in each row.  In PHP code not shown above, I will have  avarible to compare with the user_id for my `WHERE` clause.

I simply want to add some type of `boolean` to this query where it makes a new column to show if the `user_id` matches the current logged in user with a true/false.

Ultimately, I am printing this out in JSON and pushing to Java for an Android app.  In the app, I want any item in the `istView` to appear "bold" if the SQL query finds any "true" matches.  The last point doesn't relate to SQL, I just want to explain the application.

Can this query be modified in this way?

Comment: Do you mean {$user} - like you're passing a variable from PHP?

Comment: New problem... Sorry but i could not understand what exactly your problem is. What is your expectation? I was thinking you want to add a field to the results with true or false values which is already done! Currently each row has true if `user_id` equals `$user` variable or false otherwise. Isn't it what you want? If not, can you explain more about your expectation?

Comment: Well let's say there is one item that was rated three time by three people including me. I want the item to be displayed ONE time with a "1" (for `isMatched`) because I rated it and I am logged in.  If I wasn't one of the three, it should be "0". In the updated query, it prints out the item three times and shows 1,0,0 as the `isMatched` data. It should just print out once and have "1".

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2):

It may work:

Edit beggining of your SQL like this:

```
$result=mysql_query("
            SELECT i.item,
            IF(i.user_id={$userID},1,0) AS isMatched, /* Added this line assuming you have user IDs in i.user_id column of DB and $userID var of PHP contains current user ID */
            r.ratetotal AS total,
            c.commtotal AS comments,
            r.rateav AS rate
            FROM items AS i
            LEFT JOIN master_cat AS c
                ON (c.cat_id = i.cat_id)
            LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT item_id, 
                COUNT(item_id) AS ratetotal, 
                AVG(rating) AS rateav 
                FROM ratings GROUP BY item_id) AS r 
            ON r.item_id = i.items_id
            LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT item_id, 
                COUNT(item_id) AS commtotal 
                FROM comments GROUP BY item_id) AS c
            ON c.item_id = i.items_id
            WHERE c.category = '{$cat}'  AND i.spam < 30
             {$order};");
```

Now, you will have `isMatched` on your results which holds 0 or 1 values.

Comment: I like where this is going.  I tried that and it shows false on everything.  One thing I noticed is, shouldn't it be `r.user_id`? "i" is the table carrying `items` and `items_id`. (that table also has `user_id` but not in the sense that I need here.  I actually have `user_id` in the r (`ratings` table).  But when I changed it it said unknown field....

Comment: Edit:  I see why, "r" isn't defined as ratings table.  But "i" is for items table which DOES have user_id (just the wrong one).  I think I can fix this, I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe mysql has a true boolean type. I usually use tinyInt and set to 0 or 1.

You can use a mysql IF statement in your select query. Assuming your user table is u and your user id field is user_id

```
 IF (u.userId = '{$user_id}', 1, 0) as user_boolean
```

However, I'm not sure if this would actually work with your query, as your query is grabbing aggregate data, not an individual user's rating. I'd have to have more information (like the tables, fields, and relationships) to help further.

Comment: Thank you.  Using this method, I have ALMOST made this work.  Edited query to reflect this and explained new issue

Comment: glad to help! I'm a little confused by your implementation of the IF statement. I'm not sure what '{user}' is in this case, and why it is being compared to 1 (unless that's just for testing?).

Comment: Sorry, typed wrong code.  Updated now.  Should be `IF (ra.user_id = '{$user}', 1, 0)`  in other words, is the value of the user_id column = to the logged in user (which is that PHP variable).  Now it is adding a row for each rating.  If something was rated four times it prints out four lines comparing it to the logged in user. In hindsight, I kind of see WHY it is doing this.  But I just want it to do it once.  Yes or no.  Not sure if possible.

Comment: It seems I need to GROUP BY item_id in the ratings table.  And if any of those contain logged in user, it should be 1, if none, 0.  I may need a sub-query here?